# Inconsistent default behaviour of String.Comparison/CompareString with hyphens

Tags: .net, winapi, string-comparison

The default behaviour of both CompareString (Win32) and String.Compare (.NET) appears to behave in a manner which makes it largely useless. But maybe I'm missing something. Consider the following .NET example:

```cs
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
  class Program
  {
    static string CompareStrings(string str1, string str2)
    {
      int result = String.Compare(str1, str2);
      if (result < 0)
        return "<";
      else if (result > 0)
        return ">";
      else
        return "=";
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string s1 = "---dta-----";
      string s2 = "DTA";
      string s3 = "---DTA---";

      Console.WriteLine("S1 {0} S2", CompareStrings(s1, s2));
      Console.WriteLine("S2 {0} S3", CompareStrings(s2, s3));
      Console.WriteLine("S3 {0} S1", CompareStrings(s3, s1));
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
S1 < S2
S2 < S3
S3 < S1
```

Which is clearly useless for any sensible sorting algorithm as S1 cannot be simultaneously less than and greater than S3.

(NB. Exactly the same behaviour can be demonstrated using the Win32 CompareString function using default parameters)

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd318144%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for CompareString:

> "CompareString [...] default[s] to use of a "word sort" technique. For
>   this type of sort, all punctuation marks and other nonalphanumeric
>   characters, except for the hyphen and the apostrophe, come before any
>   alphanumeric character. The hyphen and the apostrophe are treated
>   differently from the other nonalphanumeric characters to ensure that
>   words such as "coop" and "co-op" stay together in a sorted list.

Which probably goes some way to explaining why this example is exhibiting this odd behaviour, and why specifying the SORT_STRINGSORT flag (with CompareString) produces a "sensible" result (in .NET specifying StringComparison.InvariantCulture also fixes things, although clearly this is not entirely equivalent).

My question is this - can anyone tell me under what circumstances the default behaviour would be desirable, or is it just a bug?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with CASE? because "a" < "A".

Comment: The case sensitive nature of the comparison is certainly a factor.  A case _insensitive_ version of the above example defines a consistent ordering of s2 < s3 < s1. 

The problem I am seeing is that that the default behaviour is internally inconsistent: s1 < s2 < s3 but simultanously s1 > s3.

Comment: Does specifying `StringComparison.Ordinal` in .NET also fix things? Also, note that the documentation for `String.Compare` recommends using the `Compare(string, string, StringComparison)` method when comparing strings. I think you'll find that using `StringCompare` with defaults is not recommended. "It doesn't do what you think it should do."

Comment: Specifying `StringComparison.Ordinal` does produce a consistent ordering.  Specifying `StringComparison.CurrentCulture` is entirely equivalent to the default behaviour (ie broken).  Sorting for user-facing purposes would therefore require the fully qualified call ie `String.Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.StringSort)` which I guess is fair enough. I'm just surprised that the defaults are so broken!  Out of interest do you have a source for that quote "It doesn't do what you think it should do" or is it one of your own? :)

Comment: I came up with "It doesn't do what you think it should do" independently, although I don't claim that I was the first to use it. It was something to keep in mind when I was working on a particular project that I inherited from a rather eccentric programmer.